# Google Maps China Satellite Map and Road Map Do Not Correspond

Tags: google-maps

When using Google Maps JavaScript API, the satellite view and roadmap view for Google Maps do not line up. There seems to be a shift from one to the other; that is, where it shows a road in the satellite view, the same road is shifted a bit to the right in the roadmap view.

The same is true when using Google Maps straight from [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com). Is there a programmatic fix for this issue? This doesn't seem to be a problem for U.S. maps, just China.

Comment: send a bug-report to google

Comment: This issue has apparently been present for several years (see this posted, dated 2010: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/ambcCIPTQiI) I doubt at this point Google is going to change anything, since they haven't done anything for at least the past 2.5 years. I'm asking if there is any way to manipulate the GM JavaScript API or similar methods to fix this.

Comment: @Dr.Molle this doesn't seem off topic at all. we're looking for a programmatic workaround for a javascript api. i am having the same issue in south america.